# how to navigate through each character in Open Office

Tags: java, openoffice-writer, uno

I'm making an extension in java for OpenOffice and I need to do something on each character.

On word I've been able to do it using :

```
foreach item in doc.characters
```

Is there something similar in OpenOffice Java API?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that counts all characters in a document.

```java
xText = xTextDocument.getText();
XTextCursor xTextCursor = xText.createTextCursorByRange(xText.getStart());
int num_chars = 0;
while (xTextCursor.goRight((short)1, false)) { num_chars++; }
System.out.println("Found " + num_chars + " characters.");
```

However if there are objects such as tables or frames, then a single text cursor will not work.  Using the [view cursor](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Writer/API/View_cursor) handles tables and frames but is much slower.  See section 7.14.2 of [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) for more complete examples.

Another approach is to enumerate all text content in the document, as in section 7.16.3 of Andrew's document.  Related information for Java is also in the [Dev guide](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Text/Iterating_over_Text).  Then for each text portion, iterate over it by creating a text cursor, which should be reasonably fast.

Comment: with this code I have the number of word and spaces but not the number of characters, how can I change this?

Comment: When I tested this code, it showed the number of characters as expected.  Calling [goRight()](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/XTextCursor.html#goRight) goes `nCount` characters at a time.  Did you perhaps use a [word cursor](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/XWordCursor.html) instead?

Comment: I use the exact same code as above (plus the code I want to be done) and it counts the words and spaces instead of characters.

Comment: You could filter the spaces or check whether the character is a space or not.